# Dynamic object allocation using array of dynamic pointers - what delete to use?

Tags: c++

Can someone help me understand these examples?

I think following code generates an array of 10 pointers that are using automatic memory allocation. Since we are using dynamic memory allocation for objects, pointers to the objects in array are lost when array goes out of scope, but objects remain in the memory until delete is called.

```
MyClass* c[10];
c[0] = new MyClass();
```

I guess the following example generates array of ten objects that are using dynamic memory allocation. We have to use delete[] to delete array and objects.

```
MyClass* d = new MyClass[10];
```

I guess in the following example we are allocating an array of 50 pointers to object. Do we have to call delete[] or delete or both here?

```
MyClass** b = new MyClass*[50];
b[0] = new MyClass();
```

I know that there are better things I could use to manage memory allocation, but I am forced to use new and delete. Can someone check if my understanding is correct and explain what delete I have to use in third example?

Thanks.

Comment: For every `new` there must be a matching `delete` and for every `new[]` there must be a matching `delete[]`. For the third example you must call `delete` on all 50 pointers and then `delete[]` on the entire thing.

Comment: If you call `new` with `[]` then call `delete` with `[]`.  BUT stop using `new` and `delete` use one of the smart pointers instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I think following code generates an array of 10 pointers that are
>   using automatic memory allocation. Since we are using dynamic memory
>   allocation for objects, pointers to the objects in array are lost when
>   array goes out of scope, but objects remain in the memory until delete
>   is called.
>
> ```
> MyClass* c[10];
> c[0] = new MyClass();
> ```

Correct. When the array goes out of scope, the allocated `MyClass` instance will stay alive, but you have missed your chance to deallocate the memory until the process ends (in which case the OS will free the memory).

> I guess the following example generates array of ten objects that are
>   using dynamic memory allocation. We have to use delete[] to delete
>   array and objects.
>
> ```
> MyClass* d = new MyClass[10];
> ```

Correct.

> I guess in the following example we are allocating an array of 50
>   pointers to object. Do we have to call delete[] or delete or both
>   here?
>
> ```
> MyClass** b = new MyClass*[50];
> b[0] = new MyClass();
> ```

First statement is correct, an array of 50 pointers to `MyClass` is allocated. Then a single instance of `MyClass` is allocated and its address is assigned to the first element of that array.

You have to call `delete` for each individually allocated element of the array first. After that, you have to call delete on the dynamically allocated array:

```
delete b[0];
delete[] b;
```

Answer (score -1):

`delete` and `delete[]` was something that was used extensively in early C++, but has now been rendered almost obsolete by the STL container classes.

The basic idea is that `new` creates a new instance of a class, on the heap, whilst `delete` destroys it. However, if you create an array of objects using `new[]`, you need to call `delete[]` to help the compiler out.

However, you can also have an array of pointers. A pointer is an object in its own right. So, if you have an array of pointers allocated with `new[]`, and then each element is allocated with `new`, you have to delete the contents of the array, one by one, using plain `delete`, and then delete the array itself using `delete[]`.

Fortunately, nowaday we use `std::vector` to store arrays of objects. The `vector` type handles all the allocation and deletion for you, so you simply have to wait for its lifetime to cease and it delete the objects for you.

Comment: Also recommend replacing references to the heap with dynamic storage. You don't see many, but it's possible to implement C++ without a heap.

Comment: Bjarne Strousup himself says that new and delete are essentially obsolete.